# width and height in canvas are not accurate

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to draw a canvas with width `x*100px` and height `y*100px`

```
var x=6,y=5;
var canvas = document.getElementById('game');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.style.width=(100*x)+"px";
canvas.style.height=(100*y)+"px";

for(var i=0;i<x;i++)
    for(var j=0;j<y;j++)
    {
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";
        ctx.fillRect (i*100, j*100, 100, 100);
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
        ctx.strokeRect(i*100, j*100, 100, 100);
    }
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vfush77n/1/)
but it looks like the width and height of each tile in the grid are not `100 px`, Why is that? and how can I set the width of each tile exactly to `100px`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
canvas.width=(100*x);
canvas.height=(100*y);
```

It seems a bit strange, but `canvas` is one element type that does *not* use CSS styling for its width and height. The number of available physical pixels is very relevant to the way that it draws, so it can't be left as a transient, derived CSS value (ie, `width: calc(300vw - 100% - 20px);`). That said, it's usually a good idea to have width/height change on a browser resize if you're making the web page responsive.